# Prevent cycling with arrow key from processing userform checkbox

Tags: vba

I created a userform with a series of checkboxes for a daily attendance log.

Each required attendee has a checkbox, the macro dumps it into Excel in a log.

Everything works except moving between checkboxes using the arrow keys causes them to become checked!

Cycling through with tab does not do this.

I've noticed it's only on the release of the arrow key.

Comment: AFAIK arrow keys aren't meant for navigating between between form controls. The TAB key is.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you.  I guess my question then is - how do I create a userform that is functional but not confusing for a user base (other than myself) that is used to using arrow keys to navigate?  Any suggestions?

Comment: You can handle each control's `KeyDown` event and capture arrow keys (I *think* - need to test it), locate the control with the next/previous `TabIndex`, and `SetFocus` on that control. Quite a lot of work to end up with a form that behaves like nothing in Windows TBH.

Comment: Oh, they're checkboxes... I don't think you can handle keydown on these.. hmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Here's how I solved it:

- Declare a public variable (e.g., keyboard)
- For each checkbox in your userForm, create event Subs for _KeyUp
- In each of these Subs, check if one of the arrow keys was pressed; if so, turn 
      keyboard to true.
- Create event Subs that check if keyboard = true, and if so, undo the .value = true to 
  .value = false

I used a function (arrowModerator) to handle it all, because for other checkboxes, if arrowModerator was true, other stuff happened). Here's how that looked with two of my checkboxes:

```
Public keyboard As Boolean      ‘or Private keyboard as Boolean


Private Sub CB_3_Change()
    Call arrowModerator(Visit2, -1, "3")        ‘Visit2 is the name of my userForm 
End Sub
Private Sub CB_4_Change()
    Call arrowModerator(Visit2, -1, "4")
End Sub


Private Sub CB_3_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Call arrowModerator(Visit2, CInt(KeyCode))
End Sub
Private Sub CB_4_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    Call arrowModerator(Visit2, CInt(KeyCode))
End Sub


Public Function arrowModerator(ByRef uForm As UserForm, keyboardInt As Integer, Optional cbString As String)
    If keyboardInt = -1 Then
        If keyboard = True Then
            uForm.Controls("CB_" & cbString).value = False
            keyboard = False
        ElseIf uForm.Controls("CB_" & cbString).value = True Then
            arrowModerator = True
        End If
    ElseIf keyboardInt > 36 And keyboardInt < 41 Then
        keyboard = True
    End If
End Function
```

I find the order of (formName)_Change, _AfterUpdate, _Exit, _Enter very confusing when they become tied to _keyPress, _keyDown, and _keyUp.  I found the the _Change event occurs after the _keyUp event, so basically the procedure above catches the "change" (aka the turning of the checkbox to .value = true) and reverses it.

Answer (score 0):

- Select the UserForm in the VBEditor
- Press <kbd>F4</kbd>
- Sort by category
- Below "cycle" locate "Enabled"
- Select "False"

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but now it won't let me select any of the checkboxes, or execute the command button.

Comment: @BenJ. - try to take a look at all the properties one by one, there could be something that helps. Worst case scenario, bind the arrow keys to an empty `Sub`.